# iOS - Drawing on a UIImage increases the image file size drastically

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

I am working on an image drawing app wherein user can sketch on top of an image. 
But after sketching on the image for some time, the image file size increases drastically. (e.g if a 1.6 mb jpeg image is sketched for some time, it becomes 2.3 mb. Size increases depending upon the amount of sketching)
If I do the same amount of sketching on an image using Preview in a Mac, it doesn't effect the image file size at all. Below are the sample images before and after editing (as the image upload limit here is 2 mb, i did only a small amount of sketching)

[Image before editing - 1.6 mb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBHoX.jpg)

[Image after editing - 2 mb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNGXl.jpg)

Not sure what is causing the drastic increase in image file size. PFB the code snippet.

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    currentLocation = [touch locationInView:containerImgVIew];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawingView.frame.size);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [drawingView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawingView.frame.size.width, drawingView.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1];
    CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, slider.value);
    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, location.x, location.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, currentLocation.x, currentLocation.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

    drawingView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    location = currentLocation;
}

 //  touchesEnded method implemented same as touchesMoved

- (IBAction)saveButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_originalImageSize, YES, containerImgVIew.image.scale);

   CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeNormal);
   [containerImgVIew.image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

   CGFloat scale = _originalImageSize.width / drawingView.frame.size.width;
   CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), scale, scale);
   [drawingView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

   UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   NSData *jpgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(viewImage, 1);
}
```

The file size of the image after drawing for some time is much more than the original image size. I tried with png images but the results are same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Photos on iPhone are stored as JPEG files. JPEG files are always compressed. "...must not use compression" is not an achievable requirement.

Photos taken with the device camera are store at approximately 0.75 quality (i estimate). When you instantiate a UIImage from a JPEG the compressed data on the disk is decompressed and a full size uncompressed image exists in RAM while you edit it. This in-memory copy is slightly degraded having been through JPEG compression and decompression once.

You make edits to the uncompressed image in memory. When you save your changes, you compress the image data once again as a JPEG. You call `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` and choose a compression level. Choosing a value around 0.75 should give you a similar file size to the image you loaded.

Each time you compress an image with JPEG format, you slightly degrade it. At high JPEG quality settings these degradations are quite imperceptible. This iterative degradation just part of working with a lossy compression format like JPEG.

Comment: Thanks for explaining @alexkent. One more doubt. When I used UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.99) without even editing and saved the data directly to disk, the image file size becomes almost half. Is this ideal behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You can choose a **lower quality** for **JPEG encoding** in your `saveButtonTapped`

```
NSData* jpgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(viewImage, 0.8);
```

Something like 0.8 shouldn't be too noticeable, and should really improve file sizes.

Comment: @Manoj let me know if it helped

Comment: thanks for the reply Piyush. But I have tried that and have observed that there is not much change in quality too. But the requirement is we must not use compression. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Ah ok lemme find some other alternative then

Comment: Photos on iPhone are stored as JPEG files. JPEG files are always compressed. "...must not use compression" is not possible.

Comment: @alexkent - so are JPEG files compressed even if we use UIImageJPEGRepresentation(viewImage, 1)?

Comment: JPEG format images are always compressed. Quality "1" just means highest quality. Uncompressed images are much bigger: 8MP images from iPhone6+ camera are ~2MB as JPEGs, but ~22MB when uncompressed. PiyushSharma's answer is the correct one.

Comment: So is there no other way to avoid drastic increase in size on image editing instead of adjusting its quality at the end? Maybe by using a different algorithm or api or library. In preview in Mac, image editing does not cause any increase in size.

Comment: Expanded my comment into an answer, see below. When you a JPEG in Preview.app on Mac it saves it again with JPEG compress at a similar quality level to the original image, so usually file size doesn't change much.